# he had few years ago

Tags: word-choice

Federer, a Tennis player lost at Wimbledon to Djokovic. Can we say

> He has not been in the classic form as he had few years ago.
>
> He is not in the classic form as he had few years ago.

Are these sentence right and which is best to use?

Comment: Simply asking whether a text is right, or which text to use, is proofreading/writing advice (off topic). Please see the [help].

Answer (score 3):

Neither is correct.  It should be

> He has not been in the classic form as he had been a few years ago.
>
> He is not in the classic form as he had been a few years ago.

Both sound a little strange to me, but the first one would definitely be the one to go with.

Comment: All of these should be ***a*** _few years ago_. And an _as_ clause is unlikely with _the_ classic form. Don't worry about perfects and sequence of tenses; work on articles first.

Comment: The first part of your final sentence just about sums it up for me. Some might say it doesn't have *exactly* the same meaning, but I think what you'd be most likely to hear from native speakers would be something more like *"He has not shown the classic form he had a few years ago"*.

Comment: Well, that was a stupid mistake... I will correct it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, I think ""He has not shown the classic form **of** a few years ago." is more natural for a native speaker.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Actually, I think that both your & FF's options are equally valid for a native speaker, but, if pushed, I would go with FF's.

Comment: @TrevorD: Really! We clearly grew up in different parts of the English-speaking world. I find FF's a bit artificial.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens As your profile shows no location, I wouldn't know!